# getJSON not working in Xcode 4.2 and ios5 using PhoneGap1.1.0

Tags: cordova, ios5, xcode4.2

i m creating an iphone app using phonegap, ios5 and xcode 4.2 . the code is as follows. the getjson code is not even called

```
    does xcode4.2, ios5 recoganise getjson calls?

     `$.getJSON("http://192.168.2.215:8070/HelloWorld.ashx/ValidateDevice?DeviceId=c852423e02146845d302e2c221a08fc00df3abc7&jsonp=?",
             function(jsonp) {
         //alert("JSON Data: " + jsonp.result);




});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. alert(jsonp);
2. adding the remote host in the trusted ones on plist
3. use the headers: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  Some of that 3 tips must solve your problem.

Good Luck!